# Start an Activity when smardcard touches NFC

Tags: android, nfc

I'm building a prototype which should be able to do the following:

1. Open an `activity` with the message to touch the `NFC` with a smartcard.
2. If the `NFC` is touched another `activity` is opened.

The smartcard does not need to be attached all the time, a short touch is sufficient. The entire app is coded already, besides the functionality regarding opening the `activity` based on the `NFC` touch. I have tried several solutions and nothing works.

Is there a possibility to trigger the new `activity` by the touch of a smartcard or by any touch event of the `NFC`? Thanks for your help.

P.S: The prototype will be for demonstrating that a smartcard should trigger a certain event, the smartcard's content does not matter at all ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily achieved through adding an [Intent Filter](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) to your app, specifically one for [NDEF_DISCOVERED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED).

```
 <activity
        android:name="your.package.name.NfcActivity
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <data android:mimeType="application/your.package.name.your.mimetype"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is one of the mentioned "several solutions" I've tried and it didn't work. Could there be a "problem" with the smartcard?

Comment: Possibly. Not being stupid, but is it possible that the smart card isn't NFC? I was under the assumption that they're usually RFID.

Comment: I know for sure that it is NFC ;) but not for sure whether it's broken or not. Is there another option to test if the card is the problem?

Comment: [This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inoapp.cardinfo) app seems to do a good job of checking any NFC cards that I have in the house, see if you have any luck with it.

Comment: Thanks, it indeed was a broken card and it works fine with your code now.